# Can Cloud Dataflow streaming job scale to zero?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I'm using Cloud Dataflow streaming pipelines to insert events received from Pub/Sub into a BigQuery dataset. I need a few ones to keep each job simple and easy to maintain.

My concern is about the global cost. Volume of data is not very high. And during a few periods of the day, there isn't any data (any message on pub/sub).

I would like that Dataflow scale to 0 worker, until a new message is received. But it seems that minimum worker is 1.

So minimum price for each job for a day would be : 24 vCPU Hour... so at least $50 a month/job. (without discount for monthly usage)

I plan to run and drain my jobs via api a few times per day to avoid 1 full time worker. But this does not seem to be the right form for a managed service like DataFlow.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 4):

Dataflow can't scale to 0 workers, but your alternatives would be to use Cron, or [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/) to create a Dataflow streaming job whenever an event triggers it, and for stopping the Dataflow job by itself, you can read the answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859829/how-to-stop-a-streaming-pipeline-in-google-cloud-dataflow/50820574).

You can find an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/scheduling-dataflow-pipelines-using-app-engine-cron-service-or-cloud-functions) for both cases (Cron and Cloud Functions), note that Cloud Functions is not in Alpha release anymore and since July it's in General Availability release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since new SDK 2.x version, Pub/Sub source is only in streaming mode. So we need to start job as you mentioned, and then drain it by a REST call... not really simple but it's possible. About the question you mentioned:  first answer is not ok with SDK 2.x, and second answer is mine (REST api to drain).  ;-)

Comment: Ohh, it's true, didn't notice it was yours :-). Then Cloud Functions seems to be the way to go to initialize the Dataflow job, and since you're using SDK 2, then your answer to the other question will fit. Maybe this REST call could be done by another Cloud Function that is triggered when Dataflow publishes to another Pub/Sub topic when [a window has no elements in it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45447303/9910124)? Either way, I think it's just a matter to adjust this idea to your use case.

Answer (score 0):

A streaming Dataflow job must always have a single worker. If the volume of data is very low, perhaps batch jobs fit the use case better. Using a scheduler or cron you can periodically start a batch job to drain the topic and this will save on cost.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Since new SDK 2.x version, Pub/Sub source is only in streaming mode. So this solution won't be possible in this case. :-(